# Specifying the order of a Queue

Tags: java, audio, queue, sequence

I have a class that plays songs in order based on their order in the directory they're in

What I want to make it do is whenever I play a certain song, I want it to remove all the songs BEFORE it from the queue so that it only plays the songs following

This is the class where the queues are created

http://pastebin.com/NwPx2nru

Comment: **Unrelated (as a side note):** your method names are C/C++ style (using underscore to separate each word in a method's name, instead of *camelCase*). Although not critical, but just a note. Maybe this will be useful: [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could continually remove items from the queue until you find the specific song that you want to play, then stop there.  The result would be a queue containing all the items after the specific song, and nothing before.

```
public void playSpecificSong(String specificSong) {
    String nextSong = songQueue.remove();
    while (!nextSong.equals(specificSong) && !songQueue.isEmpty()) {
        nextSong = songQueue.remove();
    }

    if (nextSong.equals(specificSong)) {
        // specific song was found in the queue and is held within the nextSong variable
        // songQueue now contains all songs AFTER specificSong and nothing before
    } else {
        // specific song wasn't found in the queue
        // songQueue is now empty
    }
}
```

Edit: changed variables to Java syntax